# Export to Excel - Issue in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, export-to-excel

I have tables and using JS to export to Excel.  The `<table>` tag has some descriptions and class `(<table class="someClassName" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">)`.

When it exports to Excel, the excel file contains table's tags and values (`<table> <tr> <td>value</td><td>value</td>...</tr>`), which looks like a mess!  However, if I remove all the descriptions and class inside `<table>`, when exporting to Excel, it looks fine (without `<table> <tr> <td>...` tags).

An issue is how to make the exporting Excel look fine without remove descriptions and class inside `<table>`?  Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="dvData">
    <table class="header_detail" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Billing System</th>
            <th>Market Code</th>
            <th>Payment Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RED</td>
            <td>222</td>
            <td>$103.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BLUE</td>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>$13.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GREEN</td>
            <td>555</td>
            <td>$143.00</td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Export" class="toExcelButton" data-target="dvData" />
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $(".toExcelButton").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
            window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $(table).html());
            e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    );
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to clone the table, remove the attributes from the clone and then export the attribute-less table?

Comment: @ JDB, thank you very much!  Can you please post an example "remove the attributes from the clone and then export the attribute-less table"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) functions to solve this problem.

```js
var newTable = $('#exportme').clone(),
    wrapper = $('<div>').append(newTable);

// For each element within the table (including the table)...
$.each( $( '*', wrapper ), function( i, elem ){
  
  // Build a list of all attribute names...
  var attributeNames = [];
  $.each( elem.attributes, function( i, att ) {
    attributeNames.push( att.nodeName );
  });
  
  // Then remove them.
  attributeNames.forEach(function(attName){
    $(elem).removeAttr( attName );
  })
});

$('#result').text(wrapper.html());

// Your final table will have no attributes...
console.log( newTable[0] );
// But your original table will be untouched.
console.log( $('#exportme')[0] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="exportme" class="foo" data-bar="baz" style="display:none;">
  <tr class="firstr0w">
    <td data-foobar="baz">But keep my data!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much!  I just tried, it clones a new table with `<table><tr><td>...` inside `<div id="result"></div>` and in Excel, it doesn't remove all table's tags.

Comment: @abcidd You've got enough to work with. I think it'd help you grow as a programmer if you figured out how to integrate it with your code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an excel .CSV file?
You could move the tables items into a string with the items separated by a comma. hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you make more clear that how to make the tables items into a string with the items separated by a comma, please?